# PostgreSQL UNION don't merge lines properly

Tags: postgresql, join, subquery, union

I have 3 tables in a PostgreSQL database:

```
localities (loc, 12561 rows)
plants (pl, 17052 rows)
specimens or samples (esp, 9211 rows)
```

`pl` and `esp` each have a field `loc`, to specify where that tagged plant lives, or where that sample (usually a branch with leaves and flowers) came from.

I need a report of the places that have plants or samples, and the number of plants and samples in each place. The best I did up to now is the union of two subqueries, that runs very fast (33 ms to fetch 69 rows):

```
(select l.id,l.nome,count(pl.id) pls,null esps
from loc l
left join pl on pl.loc = l.id
where l.id in
    (select distinct pl.loc
    from pl
    where pl.loc > 0)
group by l.id,l.nome
union
select l.id,l.nome,null pls,count(e.id) esps
from loc l
left join esp e on e.loc = l.id
where l.id in
    (select distinct e.loc
    from esp e
    where e.loc > 0)
group by l.id,l.nome)
order by id
```

The point is, when the same place has both plants and samples, it becomes two distinct lines, like:

```
11950 | San Martin |    | 5 |
11950 | San Martin | 61 |   |
```

Of course what I want is:

```
11950 | San Martin | 61 | 5 |
```

Before that, I have tried doing all in one query:

```
select l.id,l.nome,count(pl.id),count(e.id) esps
from loc l
left join pl on pl.loc = l.id
left join esp e on e.loc = l.id
where l.id in
    (select distinct pl.loc
    from pl
    where pl.loc > 0)
or l.id in
    (select distinct e.loc
    from esp e
    where e.loc > 0)
group by l.id,l.nome
```

but it returns a strange repetition (it's multiplying both results and showing the result twice):

```
11950 | San Martin | 305 | 305 |
```

I have tried without subqueries, but it was taking about 13 seconds, which is too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created test layout with:

```
create table localities (id integer, loc_name text);
create table plants (plant_id integer, loc_id integer);
create table samples (sample_id integer, loc_id integer);

insert into localities select x, ('Loc ' || x::text) from generate_series(1, 12561) x ;
insert into plants select x, (random()*12561)::integer from generate_series(1, 17052) x;
insert into samples select x, (random()*12561)::integer from generate_series(1, 9211) x;
```

The trick is to create an intermediate table from plants and samples but with same structure. Where data doesn't make sense (plant has no sample_id), you add null:

```
select loc_id, plant_id, null as sample_id from plants
union all 
select loc_id, null as plant_id, sample_id from samples
```

This table has unified structure and you can then aggregate on it (I'm using [WITH](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) to make it a bit more readable.):

```
with localities_used as (
        select loc_id, plant_id, null as sample_id from plants
        union all 
        select loc_id, null as plant_id, sample_id from samples)
select
    localities_used.loc_id,
    count(localities_used.plant_id) plant_count,
    count(localities_used.sample_id) sample_count
from
    localities_used
group by 
    localities_used.loc_id;
```

If you need additional data from localities, you can join them on the aggregated table:

```
with localities_used as (
        select loc_id, plant_id, null as sample_id from plants
        union all 
        select loc_id, null as plant_id, sample_id from samples),
    aggregated as (
        select
            localities_used.loc_id,
            count(localities_used.plant_id) plant_count,
            count(localities_used.sample_id) sample_count
        from
            localities_used
        group by 
            localities_used.loc_id)
select * from aggregated left outer join localities on aggregated.loc_id = localities.id;
```

This takes 75ms on my laptop all together.

Comment: Now that seems to be working! 62 ms and 51 rows. With the plus of giving also the number of plants and samples without locality data! Tomorrow I'll make some more tests. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This should be as easy as

```
select * from (
  select 
    location.*, 
    (select count(id) from plant where plant.location = location.id) as plants, 
    (select count(id) from sample where sample.location = location.id) as samples 
  from location
) subquery 
where subquery.plants > 0 or subquery.samples > 0;

 id |    name    | plants | samples 
----+------------+--------+---------
  1 | San Martin |      2 |       1
  2 | Rome       |      1 |       2
  3 | Dallas     |      3 |       1
(3 rows)
```

This is the database I quickly set up to experiment with:

```
create table location(id serial primary key, name text);
create table plant(id serial primary key, name text, location integer references location(id));
create table sample(id serial primary key, name text, location integer references location(id));

insert into location (name) values ('San Martin'), ('Rome'), ('Dallas'), ('Ghost Town');
insert into plant (name, location) values ('San Martin Dandelion', 1),('San Martin Camomile', 1), ('Rome Raspberry', 2), ('Dallas Locoweed', 3), ('Dallas Lemongrass', 3), ('Dallas Setaria', 3);
insert into sample (name, location) values ('San Martin Bramble', 1), ('Rome Iris', 2), ('Rome Eucalypt', 2), ('Dallas Dogbane', 3);


tests=# select * from location;
id |    name
----+------------
1 | San Martin
2 | Rome
3 | Dallas
4 | Ghost Town
(4 rows)

tests=# select * from plant;
id |         name         | location
----+----------------------+----------
1 | San Martin Dandelion |        1
2 | San Martin Camomile  |        1
3 | Rome Raspberry       |        2
4 | Dallas Locoweed      |        3
5 | Dallas Lemongrass    |        3
6 | Dallas Setaria       |        3
(6 rows)

tests=# select * from sample;
id |        name        | location
----+--------------------+----------
1 | San Martin Bramble |        1
2 | Rome Iris          |        2
3 | Rome Eucalypt      |        2
4 | Dallas Dogbane     |        3
(4 rows)
```

Comment: @Rodrigo how about `create index on plant (location, id);` and `create index on sample (location, id);`? :)

Comment: It could work, but the accepted solution works really fast, even without the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test that but I think it could be something like this:

```
SELECT 
   l.id,
   l.nome,
   SUM(CASE WHEN pl.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as plants_count,
   SUM(CASE WHEN e.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as esp_count
FROM loc l
LEFT JOIN pl ON pl.loc = l.id
LEFT JOIN esp e ON e.loc = l.id
GROUP BY l.id,l.nome
```

The point is to count non null ids of each type.

Comment: Took 5 seconds, but returned 12561 rows, the vast majority with 0 for both plants_count and esp_count. And I can't add these aggregate functions to a WHERE clause.

Comment: Do you want to remove rows with both columns (pl.id and e.id) equal zero? Then try `WITH tmp AS (<...>) SELECT * FROM tmp WHERE plants_count>0 AND esp_count>0` where <...> is query above.

Comment: Now it gives the same error as one of my queries (multiplying both results and showing the result twice).